# How to Limit Decimal Places in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

In access I have tried just about everyway I can find to set the number of decimal places to 4 for a double variable yet I get 10 digits after the decimal

I have tried:

1. Table design field properties
2. Control properties
3. `Round([variable/control],4)`

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to ACTUALLY limit decimal places?

EDIT: Had an idea and will try this next
Only other thing I can think of is to use a MID/RIGHT function to cut the extra decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (convert to) data type *Currency*. It holds exactly four decimals maximum.

Also, in VBA, you can do:

```
Dim Value4 As Currency
Value4 = CCur(YourDoubleVariable)
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion! I'm going to try this and see what outputs I get

Answer (score 0):

As Gustav said, you can use Currency, or you can use `Number/Decimal`, where you can specify the number of decimals.
Both Currency and Decimal will also <strike>avoid</strike> reduce trouble with rounding totals.
I think that Decimal type does not exist in VBA so your variables should be `Variant`.

Comment: I have been using double variables. I am regularly multiplying and dividing decimals and in the calculations I have no issues with as many accurate decimals as possible but when showing it to the operator and storing it I want to keep the fields uniform. Either cutting off the # of decimals > 4 or rounding to the nearest .0001